Verifying method calls of buildable objects
Sometimes, you need to verify that a certain methods are invoked on a SUT class. Sometimes, those classes are buildable which makes it more challenging. I refer to the builder design pattern as implemented by Joshua Bloch in Effective Java
I try to do a simple test here — verify that my JDialog extension is indeed disposed once its OK button is clicked
However, without pretty clumsy mock initialization (see the second block), my test fails. Besides, I have to create my constructor public (which I'd like to avoid). Apparently, Mockito can't call private constructors
How can I achieve my task concisely and without unnecessary exposure of my class members (e.g. the constructor)?
Note it's important that no GUI elements actually get displayed (so that it passes even without a graphical environment)
Without clumsy initialization. Failure
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import javax.swing.JButton;

import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.then;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.spy;

class SimpleDialogTest {
    @Test
    void ifOkPressed_dialogDisposed() {
        SimpleDialog dialog = SimpleDialog.builder().build();
        SimpleDialog dialogSpy = spy(dialog);
        JButton okButton = dialogSpy.getOkButton();
        okButton.doClick();
        then(dialogSpy).should().dispose();
    }
}

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.LayoutManager;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class SimpleDialog extends JDialog {
    private JButton okButton;

    private SimpleDialog(Builder builder) {
        // imagine we use builder.strings for some initialization
        add(createMainPanel());
        add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private static JPanel createMainPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setSize(new Dimension(300, 150));
        return panel;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(createButtonPanelLayout());
        panel.add(createOkButton());
        return panel;
    }

    private LayoutManager createButtonPanelLayout() {
        FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT);
        return layout;
    }

    private JButton createOkButton() {
        okButton = new JButton("OK");
        okButton.addActionListener(e -> dispose());
        return okButton;
    }

    // it's bad practice to provide methods needed by tests only, but for simplicity, I'll do it in this MRE
    public JButton getOkButton() {
        return okButton;
    }

    public static class Builder {
        private Collection<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

        public Builder addString(String someString) {
            strings.add(someString);
            return this;
        }

        public SimpleDialog build() {
            if (strings.isEmpty())
                throw new IllegalStateException("Must add at least one string before calling build()");
            return new SimpleDialog(this);
        }
    }
}

Wanted but not invoked:
simpleDialog.dispose();
-> at demos.dialog.SimpleDialogTest.ifOkPressed_dialogDisposed(SimpleDialogTest.java:17)

However, there was exactly 1 interaction with this mock:
simpleDialog.getOkButton();
-> at demos.dialog.SimpleDialogTest.ifOkPressed_dialogDisposed(SimpleDialogTest.java:15)

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.11.0-M2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.11.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

dispose is invoked on real dialog, not spy
With clumsy initialization (and making the constructor public). Success
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import javax.swing.JButton;

import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.then;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doAnswer;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.spy;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.withSettings;

class SimpleDialogTest {
    @Test
    void ifOkPressed_dialogDisposed() {
        SimpleDialog.Builder builderSpy = spy(SimpleDialog.Builder.class);
        doAnswer(i -> mock(SimpleDialog.class,
                withSettings().useConstructor(i.getMock()).defaultAnswer(CALLS_REAL_METHODS))).when(builderSpy).build();
        SimpleDialog dialogSpy = builderSpy.build();
        JButton okButton = dialogSpy.getOkButton();
        okButton.doClick();
        then(dialogSpy).should().dispose();
    }
}

// btw, package-private is also fine (at least, as long as you put the test class in a corresponding package)
    public SimpleDialog(Builder builder) {


Don't assert the methods are called.  Assert their effects took place.  This isn't a place to use mocking at all.

@LouisWasserman While it may generally be true, how do you imagine it in this particular scenario? I can't display the dialog window. The CI server may not have a graphic environment

Check the number of panels, for example?

@LouisWasserman what panels?

I don't know, whatever you're adding to the resulting display elements.

@LouisWasserman it's a dialog, it's not added anywhere
